# How do you add GitHub to an Azure Resource Manager WebSite deployment template latest with the latest API Version?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

They used this resource in the previous template but this is no longer available:

```
 {
      "apiVersion": "2015-04-01",
      "name": "[parameters('siteName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "location": "[parameters('siteLocation')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "serverFarmId": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "2015-04-01",
          "name": "web",
          "type": "sourcecontrols",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('siteName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "RepoUrl": "[parameters('repoURL')]",
            "branch": "[parameters('branch')]",
            "IsManualIntegration": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-web-app-github-deploy/azuredeploy.json

Update:

This is what Visual Studio creates with the latest SDK and API.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "hostingPlanName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "skuName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "F1",
      "allowedValues": [
        "F1",
        "D1",
        "B1",
        "B2",
        "B3",
        "S1",
        "S2",
        "S3",
        "P1",
        "P2",
        "P3",
        "P4"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Describes plan's pricing tier and instance size. Check details at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/"
      }
    },
    "skuCapacity": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 1,
      "minValue": 1,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Describes plan's instance count"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "webSiteName": "[concat('webSite', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "HostingPlan"
      },
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('skuName')]",
        "capacity": "[parameters('skuCapacity')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "[variables('webSiteName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]": "Resource",
        "displayName": "Website"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "name": "[variables('webSiteName')]",
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Where should I insert the "sourcecontrols" resource? The schema validation fails.

Comment: Is this not working for you? are you getting any error messages? What is the problem you're having?

Comment: Could you share more information? I've got a template here using that pattern and I just deployed it successfully. https://github.com/christopheranderson/azure-node-native-modules-sample

Comment: Just add a new Azure deployment for a WebSite project in Visual Studio. You will get a template but I can't find anywhere how to add a GitHub connection to the template.

Comment: Which api-version are you using exactly? Why do you say the "sourcecontrols" resource is not available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you show in the original template will continue to work with the latest `2015-08-01` version. Just add the `sourcecontrols` node as a child of the `Microsoft.Web/sites` (i.e. add a `"resources"` property).

It's possible that the schema validation is not up to date, but it will still work. Nothing has changed for the `sourcecontrols` node.

Comment: Ok it works. They should fix the schema as the documentation is a pain to find.